# Polls Using CustomWebpart

Tags: 2013

I need to show Custom Polls on the webpage.I have created a custom web part and have done it with the radio buttons and code is working fine.But when I tried to use check Boxes or Drop Down while creating a question in the Survey app in share point 2013 and trying to display it I am getting an error.What should I do to resolve this error?

Any suggestions or comments would be helpful.Thanks in Advance 
 click on this link to download code:   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScK43.png): https://www.dropbox.com/s/6e7glc9klp2n97g/PollTest1WP.rar
this is error image [image]

Comment: You should share your code and the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank You nadeem I have added the link to download the code and error image also...please check them out and help me